# How should I run actions against "expression+" pattern?

Tags: java, antlr

I'm trying to match and collect all "fields" in this syntax:

`fields a b c d e ...`

I will use a string array to contain all these `a b c d e` characters:

```
fields
    : FIELDS fieldsExpression
    {  
        // always zero
        System.out.println ($fieldsExpression.value.size());
    }
    ;

fieldsExpression  returns [List<String> value]
    @{ $value = new ArrayList<String> (); }
    : Identifier
    { $value.add ($Identifier.text); }
    | Identifier fieldsExpression
    { $value.addAll ($fieldsExpression.value); }
    ;
```

Now if I do that I will get an empty array. Is there anything wrong with it?

Also, I want to know how can I match this?

```
field
   : FIELDS Identifier+
   { ... }
```

This `Identifier+` will return multiple `Identifier` but I don't know how to "match" them and "run actions" on them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
fieldsExpression  returns [List<String> value] 
  : { $value = new ArrayList<String> (); }
    (Identifier { $value.add ($Identifier.text); })+
  ;
```

Your example should also work if you adjust the second alternative

```
| Identifier fieldsExpression
{ $value.add($Identifier.text);$value.addAll ($fieldsExpression.value); }
```

Comment: Should be `@init { $value = new ArrayList<String> (); }` and `: (Identifier { $value.add ($Identifier.text); })+` anyway I got the idea :-P